# Vala: Compile for a lower GTK version

Tags: gtk, gtk3, vala

My PC is running Ubuntu 17.10 and has GTK+ 3.22.

When compiled from this environment the binaries cannot be run under Ubuntu 16.04 since the only GTK+ 3.18 is compatible with Ubuntu 16.04. How do I compile for a lower GTK runtime level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other way around should work though.

Compile the binary on the older OS version and it should work fine on the newer one.

The usual solution is to not provide binaries at all, but let the users and the distribution developers / packagers deal with the problem.

Just make sure your app is easy to compile, which means use standard build system tools like `mesonbuild` and add some build instruction in a README.md file.

Comment: I disagree. ABI is not changed between minor versions of GTK+, so you can build and link with 3.22 and use on 3.18, provided that you use in your code no symbol that was introduced after 3.18.

Comment: Yes the GTK+ ABI should not change in minor versions, but there is no technical strong guarantee that it will work. Also what about other libraries? Creating a binary that should work on distro X (or distro version X) using distro Y is just not the right way to go. This is quite different on Android or Windows where there is a curated set of libraries that are guaranteed to never change. Caveat: You always have to make sure you don't accidently use newer API functions.

Comment: No technical strong guarantee that it will work? The OP complains that `the binaries cannor be run`. Well if the ABI  doesn't change, you at least you have this guarantee: it will run. It may crash because that's an untested environment with different libraries version combination and you may encounter specific bugs, but that can be fixed. But still, it should run. Even distro have in their cycle "mass rebuilds", but even without that the thing is usable.

Comment: There's several ways to achieve this: Compile in a VM with 16.04, set up a PPA on Launchpad and let that build debs for 16.04, or simply run 16.04 on your computer.

Answer (score 2):

It depends what are your real dependencies on the GTK+ API.

Each function has at the end of its documentation a `Since:` field that tells on which version of GTK+ it first appeared. Both of your target versions are GTK+ 3, so they are ABI-compatible. So you just need to check which symbols are not found when you run your binaries compiled for 3.22 on your 3.18. Every symbol that isn't found has been added after 3.18. Every symbol with `Since:` > 3.18 can't be used, you need to use the smallest common denominator. Once the symbols > 3.18 are identified, you have 2 choices:

- either you do it the 3.18 way, and change your code to use no symbol introduced after 3.18. This means you might have to use deprecated symbols, but they will be there until the next API break (ie. GTK+ 4).
- or try to get the latest features from both versions, using something like:

.

```
#if GTK_CHECK_VERSION(3, 20, 0)
    // Do it the GTK+ >= 3.20 way
#else
    // Do it the GTK 3.18 way
    // (and ensure you have checks in your configure.ac or similar to make
    // sure configuration breaks if trying to build with a GTK+ < 3.18)
#endif
```